# How do I add Chatter onto a visualforce page? Is it possible ?

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

Hi I just migrated my portal to communities. And I've added extra functionalities such as self registration and my profile page. I'm wondering if its possible to add a salesforce chatter onto a visualforce page. the type of chatter that we have inside of our salesforce, 

 
This is what I found online, I'm wondering if i would have to use those tags.

```
<chatter:feed>: Displays the Chatter feed for a record.
<chatter:feedWithFollowers>: An integrated UI component that displays the Chatter feed for a record, its list of followers, and optionally, a header bar that allows users to show or hide the Chatter feed and subscribe to it.
<chatter:follow>: Renders a button for a user to follow or unfollow a Chatter record.
<chatter:followers>: Displays the list of Chatter followers for a record.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, these are Chatter Components for Visualforce. The simplest example to try out would be to create a page like this

```
<apex:page >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

This will display the Chatter feed for the currently logged in user. The entityID here can be the ID of a standard object, custom object, user etc.

You can read more each of these components [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm). Obviously, you can write your own Apex controllers and do a lot of custom Chatter functionality as well. One such example is listed [here](http://www.redargyle.com/blog/embedding-chatter-in-custom-visualforce-pages/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding these components to your visual force page will make it appear almost identical to the chatter feed you are used to seeing in Salesforce. I have never done it on a community page myself, but I am sure it will work. The only thing I am aware of that this does not work for is Force.com sites.